# Take average of map values in Trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a column of `Map(String(), Double())`.

I want to take the average of the (non-null) values for each key that appears in the column.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(ELEMENT_AT(action_to_score, 'x')) as x,
    AVG(ELEMENT_AT(action_to_score, 'y')) as y
FROM (
    VALUES
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('x', 1), ('y', 1)])),
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('y', 2)])),
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('x', 3)]))
) AS t(action_to_score)
```

This above query returns

```
  x    y
2.0  1.5
```

I want to make the query without hardcoding the keys (namely `x` and `y`) in the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible, because Trino does not support dynamic pivoting, the only "dynamic" option is to transform data into key-value columns by flattening map with [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) (I use succinct syntax, which allows to skip writing `CROSS JOIN` explicitly) and then performing the needed aggregation over group by:

```sql
SELECT k key,
    AVG(v) avg
FROM (
    VALUES
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('x', 1), ('y', 1)])),
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('y', 2)])),
        (map_from_entries(ARRAY[('x', 3)]))
) AS t(action_to_score),
unnest(action_to_score) as ut(k, v)
group by k;
```

Output:

| key | avg |
| --- | --- |
| y | 1.5 |
| x | 2.0 |